# How to get the name of the table GORM object is mapped to?

Tags: grails, dns, grails-orm

Say I have something like:

```
class Foo {
    static mapping = {
        table 'foo_table'
    }
}
```

How can I get the name of `foo_table` if I have a reference to an instance of this object?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Import `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder`.

To get the table name from the domain class:

```
def tableName = GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(Foo).table.name
```

And to get the table name from an instance of the domain class:

```
def tableName = GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(foo.class).table.name
```

Answer (score 16):

JamesA's answer will work, but only if table name if defined explicitly, like in the question.

If you wish to get a table name whether or not it was specified in mapping, it can be done using `SessionFactory`:

```
def tableName = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Foo).tableName
```

Comment: Using your solution for java classes:  
`String getTableName(String fullyQualifiedClassName) {
        String tableName = ""

        if (fullyQualifiedClassName) {

            Class thisClass = Class.forName(fullyQualifiedClassName, true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
            def domainObjectInstance = thisClass.newInstance()
            def grailsApplication = domainObjectInstance.domainClass.grailsApplication
            tableName = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("sessionFactory").getClassMetadata(thisClass).tableName
        }

        return tableName
    }`