# In Grails, how can I get a reference to the datasource used by a particular class?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, datasource

In the project I'm working on (in Grails 2.5.4/Hibernate 4.3) I have a bunch of different classes, using a few different dataSources. I need to determine whether two given Class objects use the same dataSource. What I would like to do is something like:

```
Boolean doDataSourcesMatch(Class a, Class b)
{
  return a.mapping.datasource == b.mapping.datasource
}
```

But of course that doesn't work since `a.mapping` is a closure. Does anyone know how to access the dataSource used by a class? I don't need to know any of the properties of the connection, just whether queries on the two classes will use the same connection.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although none of these spell anything concrete out, they may help:

1. http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-can-I-get-the-column-name-that-a-property-maps-to-for-a-domain-class-td4633766.html
2. [How to get the name of the table GORM object is mapped to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664845/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-table-gorm-object-is-mapped-to)

I haven't found anything specific, but this is all rather strange. I mean you already know and I presume this is some dynamic query otherwise you coding it would know what to query together etc.

Anyhow as a workaround, unsure if it can be since it depends on how many domainClasses we are talking about, and if this is something you have already put in place or thinking of writing up i.e nothing written in either case if you could add your own getter to all the domain classes in question

```
//
static String getDataSrc() {
  return 'data_source_a'
}

//or
static boolean canQuery() {
  return true/false
}
```

You could just check  from anywhere something like this:

```
boolean canQuery = UserAttributes.canQuery()
String currentDataSource = UserAttributes.dataSrc
```

Since they are static methods, no instantiation is required. This means if you have

userObject(1) you don't need to do:

```
User user = User.get(1)
if (user.canQuery()) {
 // this is ok
}
```

You can just call out the method directly from anywhere By referencing the upperCase class name and its method.

```
String currentDataSource = UserAttributes.dataSrc
//Where this is exactly the same as above
String currentDataSource = UserAttributes.getDataSrc()
```

E2A: The answer is:

```
import org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder

class TestController {
 //either this method
def binder = new org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder().getMapping(Photos.class)
        println "binder : ${binder.table.name}"
        println "b: ${binder.datasources}"

//Or this
        def dc=GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(Photos.class)

        println "-dc is ${dc}"
        println "${dc.datasources}"
}
```

> dc.datasources

is a list so you need to compare lists.

Of course silly me, if you are querying something like in HQL where you are giving dynamic table names ${tableA} ${tableB}

You will need to access actual domain class to be able to call `GrailsDomainBinder`

[So something like](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ajaxdependancyselection/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/ajaxdependancyselection/AutoCompleteService.groovy#L20): `def domainClass = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(domain).clazz`

would give you your actual domainClass for a given tableName. But your domain would have to be a fully qualified packaged name so that will cause you issues again.
If you querying `com.domain.users.tableA` and `com.domain.info.tableB`

So You could instead use If outside of service/controller):

```
def domainClass=Holders.grailsApplication?.domainClasses?.find { it.clazz.simpleName == tableName }?.clazz
```

or without Holders if you are declaring grailsApplication in controller service:

```
def domainClass=grailsApplication?.domainClasses?.find { it.clazz.simpleName == tableName }?.clazz
```

Comment: Also you could actually declare the data source names as static strings in each class then set data source in domain object  to that static declaration. Reusing the static string to the find out the name just like above so in the bit you have mapping = { dataSource = dataSrc } then it's just declared once per class

Comment: Thanks for your response, @vahid. If at all possible I'd like to avoid adding code to each class to return the name of the datasource. I've got a lot of classes, and that would be a pain in the neck maintenance-wise. But I'll see if I can figure out something from the links you provided. So far I've found `GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(MyClass)` which looks promising, but I get "No signature of method: static GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [MyClass] Possible solutions: getMapping(java.lang.Class), getMapping(GrailsDomainClass)"

Comment: It was in that GrailsDomainBinder I updated my answer @DavidLeaman

Comment: Thanks again; I think the answer to my question is `new org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder().getMapping(Photos.class)`. However, I have some custom kludging that is getting in the way: some of the classes I use are not native Grails domain classes, so GrailsDomainBinder doesn't seem to know about them. I'll think about this some more and possibly ask another question later.